# Improve Android Emulator's Text Quality on Linux in Default Zoom

Tags: android-emulator

Android emulator does not have good text quality in default zoom on Linux. Here's an example:
[image]

The text is not sharp and you can see it is fuzzy. However, if you zoom in on step, the quality will be fine and the text looks sharp.

[image]

How can I have a sharp quality like that of image 2 in all cases?

Desktop info:
Gnome 41.1
Resolution: 1920x1080

Comment: i have the same issue using pop os, did you find a solution ?

Comment: Nope. No solutions so far. What is your distro?

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem on Linux. But I have solved this problem. Just, we have to change the resolution of the emulator.
Following are the steps to change the resolution of android emulator:

1. Open virtual device manager.
2. Click on edit button of emulator.
3. Then click on change button.
   [image: Change Image]
4. Then select 720x1280 or 480x854 resolution.
   [image]
5. Then hit save button.